# Unable to parse multiple entries from xml to html with javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to parse multiple entries from xml to html! This is script which i wrote to do that:

```
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "distros.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var counter=0;
    for(i=0; i<30; i++){
        var level=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("for")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        if(level=="Beginners"){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<counter; i++){
        document.write('<div id="page">');
            document.write('<div id="page-top">');
                document.write('<div id="page-bottom">');
                    document.write('<div id="content">');
                        document.write('<div class="post">');
                            document.write('<h2 class="title"><span id="'name'+i"></span></h2>');
// This is the line                                                      ^^^^^^^^
//  with the error                                                       ||||||||
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            document.write('<div class="entry">');
                                document.write('<p><b>Based on: </b> <span id="'based_on'+i"></span><br />');
                                document.write('<b>Architecture: </b> <span id="'architecture'+i"></span><br />');
                                document.write('<b>Desktop: </b> <span id="'desktop'+i"></span><br />');
                                document.write('<b>Origin: </b> <span id="'origin'+i"></span><br />');
                                document.write('<b>Description: </b> <span id="'description'+i"></span></p>');
                            document.write('</div>');
                        document.write('</div>');
                    document.write('</div>');
                document.write('</div>');
            document.write('</div>');
        document.write('</div>');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "distros.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    for(i=0; i<30; i++){

        var level=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("for")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        if(level=="Beginners"){
            document.getElementById("'name'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("'based_on'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("based_on")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("'architecture'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("architecture")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("'desktop'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("desktop")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("'origin'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("origin")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("'description'+i").innerHTML=
            xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

well... guess what, it's not working!
This is the small part of xml file I'm trying to parse:

```
<linux>

<distributions>

    <distribution>
        <name>Mint</name>
        <for>Beginners</for>
        <based_on>Debian, Ubuntu</based_on>
        <architecture>i386, x86_64</architecture>
        <desktop>Fluxbox, GNOME, KDE, LXDE, Xfce</desktop>
        <origin>Ireland</origin>
        <description>Linux Mint is an Ubuntu-based distribution whose goal is to provide a more complete out-of-the-box experience by including browser plugins, media codecs, support for DVD playback, Java and other components. It also adds a custom desktop and menus, several unique configuration tools, and a web-based package installation interface. Linux Mint is compatible with Ubuntu software repositories.</description>
    </distribution>

    <distribution>
        <name>Ubuntu</name>
        <for>Beginners</for>
        <based_on>Debian</based_on>
        <architecture>i686, x86_64</architecture>
        <desktop>KDE, LXDE, Unity, Xfce</desktop>
        <origin>Isle of Man</origin>
        <description>Ubuntu is a complete desktop Linux operating system, freely available with both community and professional support. The Ubuntu community is built on the ideas enshrined in the Ubuntu Manifesto: that software should be available free of charge, that software tools should be usable by people in their local language and despite any disabilities, and that people should have the freedom to customise and alter their software in whatever way they see fit. "Ubuntu" is an ancient African word, meaning "humanity to others". The Ubuntu distribution brings the spirit of Ubuntu to the software world.</description>
    </distribution>

    <distribution>
        <name>Fedora</name>
        <for>Experienced</for>
        <based_on>Independent</based_on>
        <architecture>i686, x86_64</architecture>
        <desktop>GNOME, KDE, LXDE, Openbox, Xfce</desktop>
        <origin>USA</origin>
        <description>The Fedora Project is an openly-developed project designed by Red Hat, open for general participation, led by a meritocracy, following a set of project objectives. The goal of The Fedora Project is to work with the Linux community to build a complete, general purpose operating system exclusively from open source software. Development will be done in a public forum. The project will produce time-based releases of Fedora about 2-3 times a year, with a public release schedule. The Red Hat engineering team will continue to participate in building Fedora and will invite and encourage more outside participation than in past releases. By using this more open process, we hope to provide an operating system more in line with the ideals of free software and more appealing to the open source community.</description>
    </distribution>

    <distribution>
        <name>Debian</name>
        <for>Advanced</for>
        <based_on>Independent</based_on>
        <architecture>amd64, armel, hppa, ia64, i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, sparc64, x86_64</architecture>
        <desktop>AfterStep, Blackbox, Fluxbox, GNOME, IceWM, KDE, LXDE, Openbox, WMaker, Xfce</desktop>
        <origin>Global</origin>
        <description>The Debian Project is an association of individuals who have made common cause to create a free operating system. This operating system is called Debian GNU/Linux, or simply Debian for short. Debian systems currently use the Linux kernel. Linux is a completely free piece of software started by Linus Torvalds and supported by thousands of programmers worldwide. Of course, the thing that people want is application software: programs to help them get what they want to do done, from editing documents to running a business to playing games to writing more software. Debian comes with over 20,000 packages (precompiled software that is bundled up in a nice format for easy installation on your machine) - all of it free. It's a bit like a tower. At the base is the kernel. On top of that are all the basic tools. Next is all the software that you run on the computer. At the top of the tower is Debian -- carefully organizing and fitting everything so it all works together.</description>
    </distribution>
</distributions>
```

Comment: Holy `document.write()` overflow, Batman!

Comment: I've used document.write() that much so i don't get "lost" in the script... it's easier to navigate, and it has hierarchical organization! (Just don't say: "Why didn't you use document.write("Hello / world"); 
Your comment was truly unnecessary, **Robin**! If you don't want, or don't know how to help, why do you have to make fun of others?

Comment: Can you provide an XML sample? Also, is transforming the XML on the server an option? (Don't insinuate that I don't want or am unable to help. You'd be surprised.)

Comment: Part of xml file is in the original question (now). I've edited the original question because I couldn't post it in comment (to many characters).
Using xml, and transforming is not the option... it **must** be done as I'm trying to do it... (College project) Thank you for your interest in helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
var brojac=0:
var lvl=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("for")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//---------------------------------------- ^
for(i=0; i<30; i++){
    if(lvl=="Beginners"){
        brojac++;
    }
}

for(j=0; j<brojac; j++){
```

---

The marked **i**  is unknown at this place, so the whole line will fail.(usually the whole script should stop from executing there, you should receive an exception)

The loop that should increment **`brojac`**  will do nothing(**`lvl`** will never be "Beginners") and the last of the lines will never run, because brojac will always be 0

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I can't believe I didn't see that... I've corrected my file... (BTW I've renamed "brojac" to counter and "lvl" to "level")!
Just to check if the first FOR loop does the job, I've commented the second FOR loop and put in script document.write(counter)... and it worked! So probably, error is in the second loop... JavaScript console says this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string for the line I've marked! Thank you Dr.Molle, again, for your reply!

Comment: the marked Line should be: `document.write('<h2 class="title"><span id="name'+i+'"></span></h2>');` (the same for **based_on**) There  are also errors in `document.getElementById("'name'+i")` , it should be `document.getElementById("name"+i)`
---the same for based_on again

Comment: OK... now we are getting somewhere! Now, it does print the table for all results (12 of them) but still doesn't parse the data! Looked in JavaScript console and it says:
document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML -- Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. That probably means that the first script wasn't finished, and the other already started parsing data! So I've put the second script to **head** tags, and in **body** added action onload="Show()"... (Show() was added to second script in **head**section) But that didn't work. Any suggestions? BTW thank you so much for your help! ;)

Comment: The runs of the first loop are variable(defined by counter) , but the 2nd loop runs 30 times, so you will receive an error in the 2nd loop when counter < 30 .

Comment: Thank you... that was very helpful! I've managed to save all indexes of "Beginners" to an array and after that used array elements in the for loop.
Thank you for helping me Dr.Molle! Cheers.